# Is the following intersection of a set and a $\sigma$-algebra also a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Consider the statistical experiment of a dice roll. A probability space with $\left\{\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P\right\}$. Now $\Omega =\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, and $\mathscr{F}$ is the  $\sigma$-algebra containing all the subsets of $\Omega$, while $P$ is the associated probability measure. Suppose we know that the outcome of the experiment is contained in the set $B=\{2,4,6\}$, while we consider the possibility of $A=\{1,2,3\}$. Clearly $A\cap B=\{2\}$.
My book says that, since the sample space has shrunk, $\mathscr{F}$ will also shrink in this way: $\mathscr{F}\cap B=\left\{ A\cap B, A \in \mathscr{F}\right \}$ and asks me to check whether this is a  $\sigma$-algebra.

1. Shouldn't it be $ \mathscr{F}\cap B= \{ B, \{2\},\{4\},\{6\},\{2,4\},\{2,6\},\{4,6\},\emptyset \} $, so that every subset of $B$ is in $\mathscr{F}\cap B$?
2. If the above adjustment is made, is the resulting collection a  $\sigma$-algebra?

I am pretty sure that yes it is, since it contains all subsets of $B$ and therefore their complements and I can replicate those subsets, so that infinite countable unions are contained.

Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathscr{F}$ is a sigma-algebra, and $B\in\mathscr{F}$ is any set, then the system
$$
\mathscr{F}\cap B:=\{A\cap B\mid A\in\mathscr{F}\}
$$
will always be a sigma-algebra (check this!) and is often called the trace sigma-algebra of $B$ or the induced sigma-algebra of $B$.

In your case where $\mathscr{F}=\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ is the power set of $\Omega$, then 
$$
\mathscr{F}\cap B=\mathcal{P}(\Omega)\cap B=\mathcal{P}(B).
$$
The last equality should be pretty obvious, but if it is not, then you can just prove it by showing two inclusions.

Comment: +1. One might mention explicitly at least once that in this context the notation $\mathscr{F}\cap B$ does not denote $\{x\mid x\in\mathscr{F},x\in B\}$ (most of the time, this would be the empty set) but the collection defined in this post after the symbol $:=$.

Comment: I would like to clarify the following: In this specific example $A=\{ 1,2,3 \}$ had a specific definition. I think that I was confused by the notation of reusing the $A$, since $A \cap B= \{ 2\}$ in the example. But here $A$ is used as an arbitrary set in $\mathscr{F}$, correct? Since with the specific $A$ and the specific $B$, $\mathscr{F} \cap B$ would just be $\{ 2\}$, right?

Comment: @option_select: Yes, exactly. One could have used $C$ instead of $A$ to avoid the possibility of confusion.

Comment: Great, thank you very much for your clarification.